# CAShapeLayer Line drawing

Tags: iphone, uiview, core-animation, intersection, cashapelayer

I am drawing line over 5 custom uiviews (Like UITableView rows) from one position to another `(X,Y axis)` using `CAShapeLayer`.

My issue is that I want to know that what view the `CAShapeLayer` (line in my case) is currently in. Is there any `CGIntersect` for `CALayer` and `CGRect` etc? I am trying to create graph using core animation instead of any chart API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check in the shape layer intersects a specific layer by checking intersection of the bounding box of the path agains the frame of the other layer.

```
BOOL doesIntersect = CGRectIntersectsRect(CGPathGetBoundingBox(path), layer.frame);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response david. But this line of code is crashing my application. I have a CAShapeLayer that i want to match with some uiview frames, whether the CAShapeLayer occur on that particular frame or not.

Comment: @york You got that the path is not the shape, right? It's the path. `CGPathRef path = shapeLayer.path;`

Comment: This is the code i am using CGMutablePathRef pointPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pointPath, NULL, 20, 25);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pointPath,    NULL, 30, 35);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pointPath, NULL, 40,45);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pointPath, NULL, 80,115);
    
    pathAnimation.path = pointPath;
    
    myLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    myLayer.path = pointPath;
    myLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
    myLayer.lineWidth = 4.0;
    myLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;
    [self.layer addSublayer:myLayer]; //Add layer in custom view

Comment: yes, it is a path not a shape. Now i want to check whether myLayer intersects with my custom views or not.

Comment: what error is it crashing with and what what are you passing for the intersection?

Comment: I am comparing like this: if (CGRectIntersectsRect(CGPathGetBoundingBox((__bridge CGPathRef)(myLayer)), view.frame))

Comment: `(__bridge CGPathRef)(myLayer)` is a layer, not a path... you should be getting the path (as I said above). That is why I called the variable "path"

Comment: Thanks david, i got the issue and able to resolve it now. It is now intersecting my my frames. thanks